# How do I set params for WS.post() in play 2.1 Java

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to perform a post with play.api.libs.ws.WS but I can't figure out
how to set the params, my code:

```
Promise<Response> promise = WS.url(Play.application().configuration()
                .getString("sms.service.url")).post();
```

**.post** takes (T body, play.api.http.Writeable wrt, play.api.http.ContentTypeOf ct)
but I don't understand how I should pass the params there.
The documentation only states:

```
Promise<WS.Response> result = WS.url("http://localhost:9001").post("content");
```

How do I set the content eg. **param1=foo** and **param2=bar**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set headers for WS.post() in play 2.1 Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937159/how-do-i-set-headers-for-ws-post-in-play-2-1-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try constructing the request like this:

```
WS.url("http://localhost:9001")
    .setQueryParameter("param1", "foo")
    .setQueryParameter("param2", "bar")
    .post("content");
```

The method `url(java.lang.String url)` returns a `WS.WSRequestHolder` reference which can be used to modify the original request using chained calls to [`setQueryParameter`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/java/play/libs/WS.WSRequestHolder.html#setQueryParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I think his question, the one that i have also, is what is "content"? in my case there is no content, and method post(), with no parameter, does not exist

Comment: I tried it with `.post("")` and it worked as well. I'll have to run it with Wireshark, later, to figure out exactly what it does with this "content" stuff. It's easier than read the code, at least for me.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm I guess I should really start looking at the imports!

I accidentally used import play.api.libs.ws.WS instead of import play.libs.WS;
When using **play.libs.WS** all the methods such as post(String string) and setContentType(String string) revealed themselves. This is how I did it:

```
import play.Play;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.WS;

public static Result wsAction() {
    return async(
        play.libs.WS.url(Play.application().configuration()
            .getString("sms.service.url"))
            .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")                       
            .post("param1=foo&param2=bar").map(
                new F.Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                    public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                       return ok(response.toString());
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: I think there may be something wrong with your `sms.service.url` setup, for accepting this request as a POST, since this string passed to post (`param1=foo&param2=bar`) is probably not being properly/strictly formatted as a POST payload.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is wrong, or at least misleading.  The code

```
WS.url("http://localhost:9001")
    .setQueryParameter("param1", "foo")
    .setQueryParameter("param2", "bar")
    .post("content");
```

will post the string `content` to `http://localhost:9001/?param1=foo&param2=bar`, which is almost certainly not what the OP wanted.  What is much more likely to work is

```
WS.url("http://localhost:9001")
   .post(Map("param1" -> Seq("foo"),
             "param2" -> Seq("bar")))
```

which posts the **form** `param1=foo&param2=bar` to the the URL `http://localhost:9001`, which is typically what the server wants.

Comment: @flurdy -- yikes, thin arrows, yes.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
WS.url(url)
.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.post("param1=foo&param2=bar");
```

This method uses an HTTP POST method to send its form request. As seen from the official documentation of Play, you should had already known of the GET method.

Comment: It would be convenient if you replace above Chinese by some commonly used English.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in something that can be converted to serialized JSON. This works for me:

```
WS.url("https://www.someurl.com")
  .post(JsObject(Seq("theString" -> JsString(someString))))
```

The sequence takes any number of JsValues which can also be nested JsObjects.

Answer (score 0):

for me the best way

```
WS.url("http://localhost:9001")
.post(Json.toJson(ImmutableMap.of("param1", "foo", "param2", "bar")));
```

Map from http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained

Answer (score -2):

The right way of doing the blocking request in play 2.1 is

```
WSRequestHolder wsreqHolder = WS.url("<SOME URL WHICH TAKES PARAMETER>");
wsreqHolder.setQueryParameter("id", "100");
F.Promise<WS.Response> promiseOfResult = wsreqHolder.get();

WS.Response response = promiseOfResult.get(); //block here

String jsonData =  response.getBody();
return ok("Client:"+jsonData);
```

I have tried it. It works

Comment: the question is specifically about post(), not get().  post requires a parameter, get does not.