# Consuming SOAP webservices Play framework 2.1.2

Tags: web-services, playframework

Hi i m new to play framework. There are SOAP based java web services running under jetty server in my back end cluster. I m developing a web based Application using play 2.1.2 which should call the SOAP web services running in the back end cluster.

I searched through google and found some links but I couldnt make out from them
http://playframework.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/web-services-using-play/

Can someone tell me what should be the code or how i should write to call the SOAP web services in play framework 2.1.2?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/ScalaWS ?

Comment: ya i looked at it. As i was trying to write in java i looked at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/JavaWS link . The SOAP web services that are running in the back end has some methods which takes arguments. I did not understand how i can call the particular SOAP method by passing arguments to that.

Comment: Passing arguments, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937710/how-do-i-set-params-for-ws-post-in-play-2-1-java . For the likely followup question, remember that for the response body you get back, you can call .xml to get a XML Elem.

Comment: thank you for that link and sorry if my question seems silly

Answer (score 2):

Play2 only supports making call to REST web services using standard GET and POST arguments. If you want to work with SOAP webservices, they use a specific XML format and their parameters are defined by WSDL and XSD files. To call SOAP services within Play2, you'll have to use a SOAP client library for Scala such as [ScalaXB](http://scalaxb.org/sbt-scalaxb)

I've been attempting this myself for a project, but I ran into a compilation error using Scalaxb and posted it on their issue tracker: https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/issues/235

Answer (score 2):

I came across this library:

http://downloads.typesafe.com/rp/play-soap/SbtWsdl.html

Even I'm faced with a situation where I have to consume SOAP based web services from within my Play application. My plan is to use the Play SOAP library. Give it a try!

Comment: do you know where can I find this library, I cannot find play-soap-sbt in any repository

Comment: I ended up using a java client where I used Apache CXF to generate the stubs, compile that as a jar and publish to the maven repo. In my Play application, I just reference this library as a dependency.