# How to send request parameters with same parameter-name

Tags: java, web-services, playframework-2.1

This question is an extension to [How do I set params for WS.post() in play 2.1 Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937710/how-do-i-set-params-for-ws-post-in-play-2-1-java)

My web service request handler is as follows

```
@POST
@Path("/requestPath")
public String addChallengersToLeague(
                    @FormParam("name") String name,
                    @FormParam("values") List values);
```

since WSRequestHolder accepts a `Map<String, String>` in `setQueryParameter` method, I am not able to send parameter list with same name.

I can send request from POSTMAN with multiple parameters having name 'values'and it works fine.

Can you suggest how to do the same using play? I am using play 2.1.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using play.libs.WS.WSRequest API

Following is a simple example

```
WSRequest request = new WSRequest("<Method>"); //Method can be GET, POST etc
request.setUrl("<service-url>");
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

com.ning.http.client.FluentStringsMap map = new com.ning.http.client.FluentStringsMap();

map.add("name", "aniket");

Set<String> values= new HashSet<String>();
values.add("1");
values.add("2");
values.add("3");
values.add("4");

map.add("values", values);

request.setQueryParameters(map);

Promise<Response> response = request.execute();
```

You can then use `response.get().getBody()` to get response body.