# Use Multimap instead of Map for sending parameters for Rest Assured Call

Tags: java, multimap, rest-assured

I am declaring a variable

```
    static Multimap<String, Object> multiList = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

and adding values like

```
    multiList.put(**key1**,value1)
    multiList.put(**key1**,value1)
    multiList.put(**key2**,value3)
```

Now, the request I am passing is like

```
    Response response = RestAssured.given().header("Cookie", SessionDetailsCedar.CSESSIONID).and().header("X-CSRFToken", SessionDetailsCedar.CSRF).and().header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8").and().header("Connection", "keep-alive").formParameters(<b>multiList</b>).when().post(<b>Some URL</b>);
```

My problem is that **formParameters(Map)** uses only Map as parameter when I would like to use Multimap instead

Comment: hi, use multiList.asMap()

Comment: Hi, tried using multiList.asMap(), but i have to send duplicate values as parameters, which is not accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multimap cannot be converted to Map as it is against Map's definition. In such case, I think you should use REST assured's another method formParam method as given in the example below:

```
 RestAssured.
    given().
            contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1").
            formParam("key1", value1).
            formParam("key1", value2).
            formParam("key2", value3).
    when().
            post("Some URL");
```

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is that is not really acceptable:

in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), in section 3.4 Query, there is no definition for parameters with multiple values.

The Good news it that it seems possible:

**1 a Map and Set< String > should do the job:**

```
com.ning.http.client.FluentStringsMap map = new com.ning.http.client.FluentStringsMap();
map.add("name", "one_value");
Set<String> values= new HashSet<String>();
values.add("1");
values.add("2");
values.add("3");
values.add("4");
map.add("values", values);
```

see: [How to send request parameters with same parameter-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910880/how-to-send-request-parameters-with-same-parameter-name)

**2 If you have few values, you can put by several List or varargs:**

https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Parameters

```
. param("myList", "value1", "value2"). .. 

List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("value1");
values.add("value2");

.param("myList", values). ..
```

https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Static_imports

**3 Another solution would be to use JSON.**

Comment: RFC 3986 is for URIs in general and does not define the meaning of query strings for HTTP URIs in particular. So it is the wrong RFC to cite. Multiple parameters with the same name are definitely allowed - however I believe some programming languages used on the back-end like PHP do not return anything except the last value for same-named parameters.

Comment: @RobinGreen . it is possible with php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php

Comment: the second option is exactly what I needed, thanks!