# WS.url post in Scala

Tags: web-services, scala, post, playframework-2.0

I am calling to a web service using Play framework. The function is:

```
 def addCustomerFunction = Action.async { implicit request =>
   val (firstName, lastName, accountBalance, dateOfBirth) = addCustomerForm.bindFromRequest.get
   WS.url("http://localhost:8080/customer").post(Map("firstName" -> Seq(firstName), "lastName" ->  Seq(lastName),
  "accountBalance" -> Seq(accountBalance), "birthday" -> Seq(dateOfBirth))).map { response =>
  Ok(response.body)
}
```

}

The error I'm getting is:

```
Cannot write an instance of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[Any]] to HTTP 
response. Try to define a Writeable[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[Any]]]
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works:

```
def addCustomerFunction = Action.async { implicit request =>
val (firstName, lastName, accountBalance, dateOfBirth) = addCustomerForm.bindFromRequest.get
val data = Json.obj(
  "firstName" -> firstName,
  "lastName" -> lastName,
  "accountBalance" -> accountBalance,
  "birthday" -> dateOfBirth
)
WS.url("http://localhost:8080/customer").post(data).map { response =>
  Ok(response.body)
}
}
```

Thanks Agemen!

Answer (score 1):

The `.post()` require a `Map[String,Seq[String]]` but you give it a `Map[String,Seq[Any]]`.  All values you pass into the `Map` should be a `string`.  You probably passed a `Int` as a parameter. Convert it by `toString` and the error will be gone.

```
WS.url("http://localhost:8080/customer")
  .post(Map(
    "firstName" -> Seq(firstName), 
    "lastName" ->  Seq(lastName),
    "accountBalance" -> Seq(accountBalance.toString), 
    "birthday" -> Seq(dateOfBirth.toString)))
  .map { response => 
    Ok(response.body)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the output you get, Map is not an instance of Writeable. You're supposed to send a Writeable with post. You'll have to transform your data using a Writeable, for instance by transforming it to JSON and using the Writeable companion object. Note that it may not be a valid input for the external webservice, so JSON may not work, but the idea is here.

You may have a look here for more details :
[How do I set params for WS.post() in play 2.1 Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937710/how-do-i-set-params-for-ws-post-in-play-2-1-java)

The answer is for Java, not for Scala. You may try to use withQueryString instead in Scala.