# setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") play framework 2.0.x

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to invoke web service but in play framework 2.0.x i am unable to invoke any web service which is encoded.

I have looked into code:

```
public static Result wsAction() {
return async(
    play.libs.WS.url(Play.application().configuration()
        .getString("sms.service.url"))
        .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")                       
        .post("param1=foo&param2=bar").map(
            new F.Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                   return ok(response.toString());
                }
            }
        )
    );
}
```

> reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14938117/4410109

i have tried the above code on play framework 2.0.8 but i am getting this error:

> error: cannot find symbol .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")

is there any way to set content type in play framework 2.0.8. ?

thanks

**EDIT**:

here is my code:

```
Promise<WS.Response> result2 = WS.url("desired-url")
            .setQueryParameter("sUsername","test")
            .setQueryParameter("sPwd","hbl@1234")
            .setQueryParameter("sMobileno","03332560744")
            .setQueryParameter("sTransaction_id","asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf")
            .setQueryParameter("sMessage","test")
            .post("content");

         WS.Response rs = result2.get();
```

it returns me invalid format error. and i have also tried it from REST Client with **form-data** and with same parameters, it also returns me same error "Invalid Format". but when i tried it with **x-www-form-urlencoded** it returns the desired result. but in play 2.0 i cant set the the content Type.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you `POST` a `Map[String, Seq[String]]` the content type will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` correctly.

```
.post(Map("param1" -> Seq("foo"), "param2" -> Seq("bar")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the "setContentType" method is available from 2.1.0.

In 2.0.8 you can just set the header

```
public static Result wsAction() {
return async(
    play.libs.WS.url(Play.application().configuration()
        .getString("sms.service.url"))
        .setHeader(Http.HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")                       
        .post("param1=foo&param2=bar").map(
            new F.Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                   return ok(response.toString());
                }
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Some information from [play! Doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/api/java/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In play 2.0 you can do

```
response().setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
return ok(response.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much @singhakash for your quick response. i will try it and let you know.

Comment: i have edited my question, please have a look into it. and response().setContentType is not avalaible. :(

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund have you tried `WS.url("desired url").setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8l");`

Comment: Yes i have. but i dont need header to be encoded. its actually params that are encoded.