# migration from play framework 2.0.8 to 2.1.0 ERROR: cache play already exists

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ehcache, playframework-2.1

I have migrated from play framework 2.0.8 to 2.1.0 and every thing seems perfect but i am getting following error:

> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ObjectExistsException: Cache play already exists]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:142) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523) [scala-library.jar:na]
>   Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: Cache play already exists
>       at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCache(CacheManager.java:1163) ~[ehcache-core.jar:na]
>       at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.x$1$lzycompute(Cache.scala:122) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.x$1(Cache.scala:120) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.cache$lzycompute(Cache.scala:120) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.cache(Cache.scala:120) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
>       at play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin.onStart(Cache.scala:138) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]

Any solution to this problem?

thanks!

**EDITED**
here is my build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.github.play2war.plugin._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

val appName         = "Lndlabproject"
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
  javaCore, javaJdbc, javaJpa,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.1.3.Final",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient"  % "4.0.3",
  "japid42" % "japid42_2.9.1" % "0.5.3",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
  "com.feth" %% "play-easymail" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4",
  "org.apache.ant" % "ant-jsch" % "1.7.1",
  "play" % "spring_2.9.1" % "2.0" exclude("play","play_2.9.1")
)

 val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(

    Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings: _*)
    .settings(Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "2.5")
    .settings(

  // Add your own project settings here      
  ebeanEnabled := false, 
  resolvers += Resolver.url("My GitHub Play Repository",   url("http://branaway.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),

  resolvers += Resolver.url("play-easymail (release)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/releases/"))   (    Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  resolvers += Resolver.url("play-easymail (snapshot)", url("http://joscha.github.com/play-easymail/repo/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)

 }
```

**EDIT**

here is result from play dependencies command

> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
>   | net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.6.0                                           | play:play_2.10:2.1.0                                           | As ehcache-core.jar                                |
>   |                                                                             | play:play_2.9.1:2.0.4                                          |                                                    |
>   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

how to exclude it?

Comment: you can see Build.scala in my question and yes 100 times .

Answer (score 1):

The log says that you have 2 cache plugins

check for duplicate dependency by doing `play dependencies`

Exclude the duplicate dependency by doing

`("play" % "play_2.10" % "2.1.1") .exclude("oauth.signpost", "signpost-core")`

in **build.scala** where (derived from).exclude(one of the duplicate dependency).

Comment: exclude that dependency in your build.scala by doing `(dependency).exclude("play","*")`

Comment: can you please write proper syntax? that would be really helpful. thanks.

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund first find the duplicate dependency by method described in my answer then do `("play" %    "play_2.10" %   "2.1.1")
     .exclude("oauth.signpost", "signpost-core")` in build.scala where `(derived from).exclude(one of the duplicate dependency)`

Comment: i have used ("play" % "play_2.9.1" % "2.0.4") .exclude("*", "*") and it has resolved all dependencies, but again i am getting same error. how to resolve this issue.? any idea?

Comment: in exclude you have to place dependency which are duplicate so thats why I told you to find duplicate dependency by `play dependency` then exclude it by `(derived from).exclude(one of the duplicate dependency)`.Btw how you are running the project from some IDE or directly from terminal?

Comment: there are lots of duplicate dependencies, so i have to exclude it one by one? and i am running it directly from terminal.

Comment: @singhkash i have posted dependency, kindly let me know how to exclude the old one

Comment: do `(dependency).intransitive()`  also have you removed play 2.0 environment variable?

Comment: yes i have already removed play 2.0 from environment variable and (dependency).intransitive() does not resolve the issue. :(

Comment: did you do `play clean` after changing

Comment: then you have to use exclude .Is that all you got on doing `play dependency`  as shown in your edited question

Comment: No, there was a big list, i just wrote one of the dependency. Can you please tell me how to exclude the mentioned dependency?

Comment: do `.exclude("play", "play_2.9.1")`

Comment: @singhkash I am sick of upgrading play.. :/ can you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111579/setcontenttypeapplication-x-www-form-urlencoded-play-framework-2-0-x/28112802#28112802